# DropzoneJS and Rails 4 - Almost there but I'm still missing critical pieces

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, dropzone.js

I'm trying to implement Dropzone.js to my Rails 4 app. I have the little box going but nothing else seems to be working. While I know it may be a piece of cake for someone on here, I've been spending about 2 days trying to figure this out.

Here's what I have and done so far:

Added:

```
gem 'dropzonejs-rails'
```

Added to application.js:

```
//= require dropzone
```

Application.scss

```
 *= require dropzone/dropzone
```

Here is the form that I want Dropzone.JS on:

[image]

What I currently have so far on my form page:

[image]

The box appears, but neither drag and drop nor any other function works...

Additional information: I'm using Paperclip and I want to be able to upload and save multiple images to each post I'm having.

I'm not sure if this is necessary but

Post.rb:

[image]

post_controller.js

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_posts, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote, :downvote]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show, :home]

def home
end

def index
    if params[:category].blank?
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    else
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id  
        @posts = Post.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
end

def show
    @inquiries = Inquiry.where(post_id: @post).order("created_at DESC")
    @random_post = Post.where.not(id: @post).order("RANDOM()").first
end

def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
end

def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save 
        redirect_to @post 
    else 
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
end

def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
        redirect_to @post 
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
end

def upvote
    @post.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to @post
end

def downvote
    @post.downvote_by current_user
    redirect_to @post
end

private 
def find_posts 
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :price, :description, :location, :category_name, :contact_number, :image)
end
```

end

**What I need help with:**

Implementing Dropzone.JS so I can upload multiple images to my post _form and have it appear on my post show page.

[image]

Thank you in advance!

---

**UPDATE**:

This is what appears: 
[image]

Comment: Please use the Stack Overflows own code snippets instead of external images. It makes the question much easier to read especially if someone isn't used to reading dark themes like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [DropzoneJS documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage) you should put the class *dropzone* on form element instead of the file upload element. After this the DropzoneJS finds all the file inputs and changes them inside the form.

So change the form generation line to

```
= simple_form_for @Post, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
```

to

```
= simple_form_for @Post, html: { multipart: true, class: 'dropzone' } do |f|
```

Comment: This got the drag and drop working. Now it's saying I'm missing template. I know this has something to do with Json, can you point me in the right direction? What to change in my controller?

Comment: When does it say that? After you click the submit button on your form? That probably means that you are missing view `posts/show` since you have the `redirect_to @post` in your _create_ method. In general that should be its own question as it isn't quite in scope of this question anymore.

Comment: No that isn't the issue. It's something to do with having JSON because dropzone requires JSON. I'm just unsure how to add JSON to my controller. I've been having show so that isn't the problem.

Comment: Then my question is still waiting for answer: "When does it say that"? After submit or when? There simply isn't enough information available to solve that yet.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, you should make a separate question about that and accept this answer as it solved the original problem of DropzoneJS not showing. The problem you see if because you don't have a JSON template for `posts/show` so create one to `posts/show.json.jbuilder` with content like `json.extract! @post, :id, :title`..

Answer (score 0):

@Loi Huynh : hi Loi! You can see examples at this site : http://sudharti.github.io/articles/dropzone-rails/

I having problems updating nested form ... if you want us to discuss this issue.
this my code :

```
<%= form_for(@product, html: {class: "dropzone", multipart: true}) do |f| %>
<div id="previews" class="dropzone-previews">
 <div class="dz-default dz-message" align="center">
   <span class="btn btn-primary">Click vào đây để thêm Ảnh</span>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" align="center">
  <br/>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Hoàn Tất", id: "submit-all", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
    <%= link_to 'Quay về', products_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my products_controllers :

def create

```
@product = Product.new(product_params)
respond_to do |format|

  if @product.save

    format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Tạo mới thành công.!.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
  else
    render json: { error: @post.errors.full_messages.join(',')}, :status => 400
  end
end
```

end

and my upload.js

$(".dropzone").dropzone({

```
autoProcessQueue : false,
paramName: "product[photos_attributes][][image]",
previewsContainer: "#previews",
init: function() {
  var myDropzone = this;
  this.element.querySelector("#submit-all").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      myDropzone.processQueue();
  });
 },
```

});

Comment: Hello! Could you post the code to your controller and show as well? Thanks a lot!

Comment: if u use paperclip and dropzonejs . u can see examples at this site : http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/ajax-file-upload-with-dropezonejs-and-paperclip-rails.

Comment: You should pay attention to the url if you don't set the class: "dropzone" in form, and also very important paramName . are you vietnamese?